# Prevent git from automatically generating user email if missing

Tags: git, git-commit, git-config

Is there a way to globally configure `git` to not automatically generate user's email, if none is set and abort the commit instead?

```
$ git commit -m "test"
[master (root-commit) 71c3e2e] test
Committer: unknown <my.user@my.very.own.hostname>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
```

This can cause serious privacy leaks if the committer is not careful enough to check `git` warnings.

Comment: You might be able to create a pre-commit hook that checks for this, and have it abort if the username and email aren't configured.

Comment: If you figure it out on your own, consider leaving it as an answer to your own question so that future readers can benefit from the solution. Or else, consider closing and/or deleting this question. Up to you.

Answer (score 8):

Set `git config --global user.useConfigOnly true`

> user.useConfigOnly
>
> Instruct Git to avoid trying to guess defaults for user.email and user.name, and instead retrieve the values only from the
>   configuration. For example, if you have multiple email addresses and
>   would like to use a different one for each repository, then with this
>   configuration option set to true in the global config along with a
>   name, Git will prompt you to set up an email before making new commits
>   in a newly cloned repository. Defaults to false.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `git` pre-commit hook, following the suggestion by [@cupcake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/456814/cupcake).

1. Create file named `pre-commit` like so:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   git config user.name >/dev/null 2>&1

   if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
       echo "Error: user.name is undefined. Use 'git config user.name \"Your Name\"' to set it."
       exit 1
   fi

   git config user.email >/dev/null 2>&1

   if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
       echo "Error: user.email is undefined. Use 'git config user.email you@example.com' to set it."
       exit 1
   fi
   ```
2. If necessary, make it executable with `chmod +x pre-commit`
3. Throw this file to global `git` hook templates:

   - On *nix systems this is located at

     ```
      /usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks
     ```
   - On Windows this can be typically found in

     ```
      %ProgramFiles%\Git\share\git-core\templates\hooks
     ```
4. Re-initialize your existing `git` repos with `git init`.

Comment: Didn't worked for me because of `[[: not found` error until I changed `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command to prevent :

```bash
git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

or even execute:

```bash
git config --system user.useConfigOnly true
```

[By default](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-useruseConfigOnly), git config `user.useConfigOnly` is set to `false`, so git will try to autoconfigure `user.name` and `user.email` while committing if unset.

But on some platforms (e.g, Ubuntu), a really wired behavior is that git won't autoconfigure `user.name` even you leave `user.name` empty, and "identity unknown" error will occur if you try to commit, so most people won't meet this autoconfigure thing at all, until you have a repo set `user.name` but not `user.email` (in short, git will only autoconfigure `user.email`).

I assume there are many people like me only want to configure `user.name` but not `user.email` globally to prevent to commit with the wrong email, and definitely don't want to have that autoconfigured "email" thing, if so, just run the above command.