# How can I prevent Git from using an email of the form username@pc-name instead of an empty one?

Tags: git, privacy, git-config

Whenever I try to use GIT it automatically enriches my commits with a lot of private data like user name, email and/or pc-name.

How do I configure GIT correctly so that it never automatically discloses my private data?

I already performed

```
git config --global user.name Robert
git config --global user.email ""
```

However my commits/pushes still contain my account and computer name which I consider to be private data.

What is necessary to make GIT not to publish my personal information into the repositories/internet?

Comment: *[...] my commits/pushes still contain my account and computer name [...]* Where, in your commits, do you see that information? Try running `git log --raw -1`. Do you see the info in question in the output of this command?

Comment: Even after explicitly setting the email it uses an auto-generated email in the form username@pc-name (pc-name includes the name and the FQDN.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56232509/52817

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running

```
git config --global user.email ""
```

clears the `user.email` field of your user-level config file, which will lead Git to assume that you haven't set your email address yet (under the assumption that no email address is specified in the repository-level config file, of course).

As a countermeasure, Git will generate an email address of the form `username@pc-name` (where `pc-name` includes the name and the FQDN) and will bake that email into your commits instead:

```
$ git log -1
commit 9cd00b7ed6206086bf332e0481092590d07626d5
Author: jubobs <jubobs@jubobs-MacBook-Pro.local>
Date:   Thu Dec 18 16:23:19 2014 +0000
```

However, it *is* possible to trick Git into using an empty email address; you simply need to run the following command instead (tested with Git 2.1.3):

```
git config --global user.email "\<\>"
```

Then, Git won't use the autogenerated email address mentioned above:

```
$ git log -1
commit 0d0bb289b293ec020b607021bbd886be5107bc7f
Author: Jubobs <>
Date:   Thu Dec 18 16:25:14 2014 +0000
```

Related: [Git commit with no email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372970/git-commit-with-no-email)

Comment: The command you posted caused a "syntax error" then executed. However slightly modified it works: `git config --global user.email "\<\>"`

Comment: @Robert Weird. It works fine on my machine. Which version of Git and which shell are you using?

Comment: @Jubobs I have git 1.9.4 installed

Answer (score 1):

In case the GIT repository belongs to a GitHub project specifying an invalid email address is not recommended. Instead GitHub specifies the following alternative (cite from [GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private)):

> If you'd like to keep your email address private, set your Git config email to **username@users.noreply.github.com** instead, replacing username with your GitHub username.
>
> Note: If you created your GitHub account after July 18, 2017, your
>   GitHub-provided no-reply email address is a seven-digit ID number and
>   your username in the form of ID+username@users.noreply.github.com. If
>   you created your GitHub account prior to July 18, 2017, your
>   GitHub-provided no-reply email address is your username in the form of
>   username@users.noreply.github.com. You can get an ID-based
>   GitHub-provided no-reply email address by selecting (or deselecting
>   and reselecting) Keep my email address private in your email settings.